# An event for when browser tab becomes active form inactive?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

Is there an event I can listen to when a browser tab becomes active.
By becoming active I mean all of the following things:

- When user switches to the tab with my website form another tab.
- When user switches back to the browser (with tab that contains my website open) from another App.
- When user unminimizes the browser (with tab that contains my website open)
- Basically when our tab becomes active from any other condition.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following event for this,

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  console.log(`Your page is  ${document.visibilityState}`);
});
```

You can check the browser compatibility of the above [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange).